# Hide Dropdown on Click

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm using a resoponsive dropdown pattern from Brad Frost's This Is Responsive -- and, because some of the links to to anchors on the same page, I'm looking for a way to force the dropdown to close on click, not just mouseout.

Pattern is here: http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/qwJvF

Code that makes it work is here:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#menu'),
          $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
          $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });

    });

 </script>
```

What I need to do is take the .active class away, onclick. Tried it a couple ways, but none of them have been the right way.

Many thanks,

-m

Comment: what if you only call preventDefault if link is other than an anchor or whatever pattern you have?

Comment: That sounds like it could work -  what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try something like this (it's ugly, but works for now..maybe you can fix it later):

```
  <script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body').addClass('js');
      var $menu = $('#menu'),
      $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
      $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');
      // added to deal with the submenu level
      $submenuTrigger = $('ul.level-2 li > a');

      $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
      });

      $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');           
      });  

      // on click, hides the submenu
      $submenuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul.level-2').css('display','none');
      });

      // on mouseenter on the main menu, shows the submenu again
      $menuTrigger.mouseenter(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($(this).siblings('ul').attr('class') == 'level-2')
        {
          $this.siblings('ul').show();
        }
      }); 

        });
    //@ sourceURL=pen.js
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabi.  That doesn't quite work.  The menu needs to work to go to #links -- it just needs to disappear afterwards.  This isn't really an issue on desktop, since moving the cursor pretty much does it.  But on a touch screen the menu stays dropped down till you tap somewhere else.

Comment: Im confused. You say the menu needs to link to anchor #links - that automatically will close the menu...

Comment: Tried to get everything into codepen and couldn't.  new.chromavision.net is the site. Two issues, both on Services: On mobile, clicking a services subnav link needs to close the menu toggle. On desktop, clicking a services subnav needs to hid the dropdown on click -- otherwise it stays open till you click somewhere else.  Really appreciate you looking at this.

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if it works for you. FYI, IE10 breaks everything.. :-/

Comment: Thanks, Fabi -- very much appreciated